# How can I make a List OR ArrayList object singleton in Spring batch application. How can I annotate a field as singleton in java spring batch/boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, singleton, spring-batch

I am writing a Spring batch application, in which there are chunks/tasks to process multiple records. 
If I have 100 records to process then multiple chunks are executed to process all the records.
Let's say in 1st chunk/task first 25 records are stored in ArrayList and processed, next chunk/task is executed to store and process next 25 records and so on..

I want to design the ArrayList in such a way that it should store records from current chunks/tasks as well as records of previously executed chunks/tasks and rather than creating new object each time for every Batch step executed.
For this case, I need to make ArrayList as singleton object so that there is only single instance of ArrayList present and I can have previous records and can also store new records from the current chunks/task.

I have tried using *Collection::singletonList()* but it returns immutable rather than 'Singleton' object. 
I have also tried to use annotation such as *@Scope*, but it gives a compilation error - " '@Scope' not applicable to field"

What can be the possible approach to solve this problem?
Is my approach to create singleton list correct, for this UseCase ?

Comment: Why? With large collections this will lead to memory issues, when  using JPA it will lead to performance issues quickly. Why do you need all the entities? It goes a bit against the design/purpos eof Spring Batch.

Answer (score 0):

Static-Final would not help because static will load class twice for 2 tasks and instance of List will be created every time the class loads.
But I found solution and that worked for me:
I have created a bean which will return the list object and have auto-wired by name in the classes that I want to access that bean, So that every time it returns me the same instance of the ArrayList

Example:

```
    Class MyList
    {
      @Bean
      public List getMyListInst()
      {
        return new ArrayList();
      }
    }
```

//Below class where we want to use above list

```
    class UserClass
    {
       @Autowire
       private List getMyListInst; // Use the same name as given in above Bean

       ....
       ....

    }
```